# Sort in block in vim

Tags: sorting, vim

I'm looking for a way to sort in selected block in Vim. The scenario is I have something like this

```
{:a
 :c 
 :b}

# after sort, it should be 
{:a
 :b
 :c}
```

How I do it now is I have to enter `:a` and `:c` to new lines, running sort on selected block and then put the brackets back later. I'm looking for a way to sort without doing this extra operation.

Comment: If a plugin is good for you, you can try _vis.vim_, see here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9869/sorting-a-column-without-altering-other-columns

Answer (score 1):

The following will reduce your effort *slightly* but still doesn't resolve it completely, basically it will sort based on what comes after the colon, then remove the brackets but it doesn't insert them again for you:

```
:'<,'>sort /^.\{-}:/ |%s/{\|}//g
```

Hope it helps, happy vimming.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is by reading the inner of the braces into a register.

```
"ayi{
```

This will copy the content, the lines, without the braces around them.

Then you can run that into the sort function

```
sort(split(getreg('a')))
```

This requires the `modifiable` flag to be set, as you're changing a non visible buffer.  It sorts the buffer `a` in place.  You could then paste that inside the braces `vi{"ap`.

Obviously you should put the while thing in a function/macro or command.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way with Ex commands. Sorting of ranges is pretty easy with `:global` and `:sort`. The following command sorts the lines *between* those delimited by curly braces:

```
:g/^{/+1,/^}/-1sort
```

But the complication here is that (in your example), the enclosing braces are *on* the same (first, last) lines as the data. We need to separate them out to adjacent lines first, and later undo that. `:substitute` can do that:

```
:%s/{\zs\|\ze}/\r/g
:g/^{/+1,/^}/-1sort
:%s/{\zs\n\|\n\ze}//g
```